# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for LinearLayout, size 0x128 max size 16384 color type 4 has context 1

Tags: android

In my app, I met the crash on Android P for the first time. The code stack trace is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for LinearLayout, size 0x128 max size 16384 color type 4 has context 1
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6812)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Now, it only crashes on Android P on such as HUAWEI P20, XIAOMI 8 devices. Any ideas?

Answer (score -5):

Finally solve the crash. In my case, I have three views doing AlphaAnimation at the  same time.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: Please provide some more details. Half baked information is not enough to solve the problem.

Comment: I solved similar problem changing "android:alpha" property of my views to a background color with transparency